# Windows RT/ Universal app, Webview offline html file

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, win-universal-app

( creating a universal app, currently working one windows phone 8.1) I am trying to get the webview to work with an offline html file but i cant really figure it out. I can get it to work with a weblink but not with an html file which is located on the shared folder.
I'm using switch statement to switch through different options. Here is a sample one with the code i use

```
 case "Test":
                ActualLoad = "Test.html";
                break;
```

Here is the one that has a link:

> `case "OnlineTest":
>                       ActualLoad = "https:www.google.com";
>                       break;`

The second one works but not the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Remarks in this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview).

Basically, you have to use something like this: `<WebView Source="ms-appx-web:///Test.html"/>`
This will work only if your Test.html file exists in your app package.